# Changes the text of a textview from a new event [Android]

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, textview

I can't change the text of `text_view_cantidad_resultados of a`TextView` from an event. This is the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_resultados_busqueda);

    text_view_cantidad_resultados = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_cantidad_resultados);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager_cards_resultados);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            Log.d("onPageSelected: ", String.valueOf(position));
             /*Here is where a want to changes the text of          
             text_view_cantidad_resultados.
             Something like                     
             text_view_cantidad_resultados.setText(position);
             */
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    });
}
```

I know that is because that object is not defined in that instance of the class (in the event), but a have no idea of how can I do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextView will accept only int value as resource, so convert your int to String add it will work,

Ex:

```
text_view_cantidad_resultados.setText(position + "");
```

or

```
text_view_cantidad_resultados.setText(String.valueOf(position));
```

Comment: LOL It's true, thank you very much. I forget how Java works, maybe there is very PHP in my head lately. :)

Comment: TextView.setText will accept an integer value as an argument but it expects that integer to be the id of a String resource which in the case of "position" almost certainly will not exist. If I remember correctly this causes a ResourceNotFoundException to be thrown.